# Bhagavad-Gita Adi Shankara Bhashya text

Tags: bhagavad-gita, commentary

Please help me with online links to Gita Bhashya from Adi Shankara, with Sanskrit text as well as English translation. I am fine if it's advertised two separate sites.

I managed to get English translation [here](https://www.shankaracharya.org/gita_bhashya_2.php) (not sure this is reliable one) but not the Sanskrit version.

Answer (score 2):

**This is from Gita Press Gorakhpur (Sanskrit - Hindi)**

> https://archive.org/details/bhagavatageetawithshankarbhashyagitapressgorakhpur_202001

---

**You can check this site named as** ****Gitasupersite****, **check this link :**

https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=1&scsh=1&choose=1

> Here in this single site you can get all of the commentaries by Great Acharya's with English and Hindi translations **(Sri
> Adi Shankaracharya, Swami Chinmayananda, Swami Ramsukhdas, Sri
> Abhinavgupta, Sri Ramanujacharya, Sri Anandgiri, Sri Jayatirtha, Sri
> Madhvacharya, Sri Vallabhacharya, Sri Madhusudan Saraswati, Sri
> Sridhara Swami, Sri Vedantadeshikacharya Venkatanatha, Sri
> Purushottamji, Sri Neelkanth, Sri Dhanpati, Swami Sivananda etc. )**

Hope these help you.
Śiva Śivā !

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the [gita supersite](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/) link given in the other answer, another good resource for the Sanskrit commentaries of Sri Shankara is the [advaita sharada website](https://advaitasharada.sringeri.net/%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%83/), that includes all prasthAna traya commentaries.

Bhagavad Gita commentary in [advaita sharada website](https://advaitasharada.sringeri.net/%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%83/) can be found [here](https://advaitasharada.sringeri.net/display/bhashya/Gita). Please note, for Gita, Sri Shankara gives an introduction and then the commentary starts from sloka 2.10.